# What tools will let me analyze automation reporting results?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for a tool that stores the history of automated test runs performed on Jenkins and allows analysis to be performed to the desired level of detail.

Today we have several Jenkins jobs that perform each different type of test (BVT, Regression, etc ...) and the history of each job is kept in Jenkins itself, which makes it very difficult to evaluate the results.

I would like to export these results and save them in other place that allows you to analyze the overall results and allow you to search in detail as well.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience I would recommend Report Portal
https://reportportal.io/

This is a standalone opensource tool powered with ML/AI and allows you to:

- Keep historical data for your tests
- Create dashboards with test automation metrics
- Perform test result analysis with assigning a categories for failures (very helpful for finding a process bottlenecks)
- Delegate part of the manual test result analysis to ML algorithm

And many more, see the website.